# Why this argument order in the prototypes of regex_match?

Tags: c++, regex, prototype, c++11

Here is a simplification of the [6 prototypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982821.aspx) of `std::tr1::regex_match`

```
regex_match(iterator1, iterator2, match_results&, regex&, flags = some_default);
regex_match(iterator1, iterator2,                 regex&, flags = some_default);

regex_match(Elem*,                match_results&, regex&, flags = some_default);
regex_match(Elem*,                                regex&, flags = some_default);

regex_match(string,               match_results&, regex&, flags = some_default);
regex_match(string,                               regex&, flags = some_default);
```

I wonder why the prototypes were designed this way:

- It seems that both `match_results` and `flags` are intended to be optional, but you should be able to provide one of them. Why not have shifted the `match_results &` argument next to the `flags` argument?
- The `regex &` argument would seem more intuitive as the leading argument.

Could somebody explain the rationale behind those prototypes?

Thank you.

Comment: `match_results&` is a reference, how is that optional?

Comment: @Xeo: Because there's an identical overload without it?

Comment: @DeadMG: Ignore my last comment then, I'm too sleepy it seems.

Comment: Just a guess that the `regex` and `flags` are considered a pair and therefore belong together. And optional parameters have to come last.

Comment: how is `flags` optional?

Comment: @Tomalak : `flags` defaults to `match_default` for every overload.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: made it more clear in the question. thank you for the comment.

Comment: For `std` "consistency-with-boost" may sound reasonable? But then again, the question goes to boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is some sort of stylistic consistency with the algorithms library.  If you think of match_results as some sort of output iterator then it sort of looks like copy, etc with an iterator range at the front, an output iterator after that and predicates after that.  The option to not store the match_results turns these into predicates like any_of, etc.

There is something to be said for consistency in a library.

That's my guess.

Comment: I like this hypothesis, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

I think I agree with you. Your proposal would make more sense.

As for "why it was chosen to be this way" there is no objective answer to that; there's certainly no evident technical reason that I can spot.

I'd put it down to design-by-committee.

Comment: I am not sure I can accept this as an answer because I am sure there must be a good reason for these prototypes and my purpose is to know why. If I get no other answer I will accept it!

Comment: I don't know what the types are, but could `flags` and `match_results` ever be ambiguous? That's the _only_ reason I could think that this might be a deliberate choice. If you want some in-person testimony from the designers of the library, this is probably the wrong place to ask.